# Exit from an SSH session but not script

Tags: bash, unix, ssh

In my bash script, I do:

```
ssh me9@some_mad_server.com;
cd ~/apple;
echo "Before Exit"
exit
echo "After Exit"
```

I never see Before Exit or After Exit. I can understand why I may not see Before Exist as my script at that stage is in another console.  But I am confused if the Exit mean my script ends and hence why After Exit never gets logged.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you show some real code?

Comment: The answer would actually depend on how your script looks like and how you run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To execute a series of commands on a remote host, you need to pass them to `ssh` on the command line, not execute them *after* the `ssh` call. Like this:

```
ssh me9@some_mad_server.com '
    cd ~/apple
    echo "Before Exit"
'
echo "After Exit"
```

This uses a multiline string to pass multiple commands. An `exit` is implicit when the end of the string is reached.

Importantly, the commands in the quoted string are executed on the remote host, while the final `echo` is executed on the local server. I've indented the remote commands for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

You can use screen for this.

```
screen -d -m <command>
```

Use screen -r to attach to that screen again

```
screen -r <screen ID>
```

Comment: It does work with the `-d -m` flags on the screen command. I'll edit.